# There is no 'Camera' attached to the "ARCamera" game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcamera

I keep getting this error in the play mode:

> "There is no 'Camera' attached to the "ARCamera" game object, but a
>   script is trying to access it."

This is in spite of having Camera (MainCamera) as a child of the ARCamera. Furthermore, I cannot find the script that uses the 'Camera' component.

Hence, I only get a black screen in game view and when building the app.

Comment: Well normally there should not be MainCamera as a child of ARCamera of Vuforia.  Are you creating it using GameObject->Vuforia->AR Camera or doing something else?

Comment: The camera component has to be on the same GameObject. It doesn't have to be the main camera, though

Comment: I added the Camera from GameObject -> Camera. It just has the Tag "MainCamera" but I'm not quite sure if it's affecting the performance. I just loaded the project from https://github.com/KeyStarr/Real-World-Object-Recognizer-Unity in which it was made in a different version of Unity so some scripts are missing such as the "HideExcessAreaBehaviour" that should have been a component of the Camera.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the camera again, and try and reference it using the index. (`transform.getchild(**index of camera in hierarchy**))`